# Passing JSON data from views to html via ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I cannot render html template with JSON data passed from views via ajax. I get correct JSON format from views and I can see the correct response in `console.log(response)`, but when I run from the browser this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/our-stores/` I get this result:

```
[{'fields': {'address': 'Kilpolantie 16',
             'city': 'Helsinki',
             'country': 'Finland',
             'name': 'K-market'},
  'model': 'shoppire.supermarket',
  'pk': 1},
 {'fields': {'address': 'Kontulankari 16',
             'city': 'Helsinki',
             'country': 'Finland',
             'name': 'S-market'},
  'model': 'shoppire.supermarket',
  'pk': 2}]
```

But instead of this output I should get rendered `ourstores.html` file. Please, find the code below:

models.py

```
class Supermarket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^our-stores/$','shoppire.views.ourstores',name='ourstores'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
def ourstores(request):

    stores_list = Supermarket.objects.all()

    response_data = serializers.serialize('json',stores_list)

    return HttpResponse(response_data,content_type="application/json")
```

ourstores.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class='col-sm-12' style='text-align:center'>
    <h2>Check out our stores:</h2>

    <div id="show_stores" onload="ShowStores()"></div>

    <div id="results"></div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

ShowStores.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowStores();
});
function ShowStores() {
    console.log("show stores is working");

    $.ajax({

        url : "our-stores",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(response){

            $.each(response,function(index){
                $('#results').append(response[index].fields.name);
                console.log(response[index].fields.name);
        });

        console.log(response);
        console.log("success");

    },
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#show_stores').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    } 

    });

};
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you expect jQuery to render HTML from JSON?

Comment: I would expect that jQuery takes the response from the views and display that response in html.

Comment: All jQuery is going to do is append the JSON returned from the request to the DOM. JSON doesn't magically transform into HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You do not render the `ourstores.html` template anywhere in your `ourstores` view. In order for a template to be displayed, it has to be rendered by the view. In your case, if the request is AJAX, you'd want a JSON to be rendered and if the request is not AJAX, the actual template to be rendered.

Your view could look something like this:

```
def ourstores(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       stores_list = Supermarket.objects.all()

       response_data = serializers.serialize('json',stores_list)

       return HttpResponse(response_data,content_type="application/json")

    return render(request, 'ourstores.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you wrote I get rendered the template, but I do not get JSON data returned from the views. I would like that the views send back data to the ajax call and that such returned data display on the template.

Comment: Hm, it should. Check if `request.is_ajax()` is `True` when the view is called via AJAX.

Comment: @Moki One other thing you could try is changing the URL for the AJAX request to append a slash (`url : "our-stores/"`). If you have `APPEND_SLASH` turned on, the AJAX request gets redirected and looses the header marking it as AJAX.

Comment: `request.is_ajax()` returns false so probably url in ajax call is not correct. I tried with the slash but it is also false.

Comment: You could stick a GET param in the AJAX request URL and check for it's presence in the view. E.g: `url : "our-stores?ajax=1"` and then instead of `request.is_ajax()` use `request.GET.get('ajax')`.

Comment: I tried this and I get raw JSON data without the template. I have also tried this `$.get('our-stores/', function(response){
         $.each(response,function(index){
               $('#results').append(response[index].fields.name);
               
         });
              
    });` but again it displays only JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for JSON response, JSON response is what you will get.
If you want to render a template, use the following:

def ourstores(request):

```
stores_list = Supermarket.objects.all()

response_data = serializers.serialize('json',stores_list)

return render_to_response('our_stores.html',
                      response_data,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then, inside your template use the passed data as {{response_data}}

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this case I am excluding javacript and ajax and render the template directly from the view. I want that html sends the request for json data via ajax to the views and then views to send back the data to ajax where they are inserted in the html tag.